# Collectors.toMap() keyMapper -- more succinct expression?

Tags: java, collections, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm trying to come up with a more succinct expression for the "keyMapper" function parameter in the following `Collectors.toMap()` call:

```
List<Person> roster = ...;

Map<String, Person> map = 
    roster
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(
                new Function<Person, String>() { 
                    public String apply(Person p) { return p.getLast(); } 
                },
                Function.<Person>identity()));
```

It seems that I should be able to inline it using a lambda expression, but I cannot come up with one that compiles. (I'm quite new to lambdas, so that's not much of a surprise.)

Thanks.

--> Update:

As noted in the accepted answer

```
Person::getLast
```

is what I was looking for, and is something I had tried. However, the BETA_8 nightly build of Eclipse 4.3 was the problem -- it flagged that as wrong. When compiled from the command-line (which I should have done before posting), it worked. So, time to file a bug with eclipse.org.

Thanks.

Comment: Note also a static import for Collectors.toMap will make the expression shorter still, NetBeans doesn't seem to be importing these for me though however.

Comment: Just stumbled over this question. Your problem was not only Eclipse 4.3, it was also JDK 8 before u112, which had similar problems. HTH.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

You can use a lambda:

```
Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getLast(), Function.identity())
```

or, more concisely, you can use a [method reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) using `::`:

```
Collectors.toMap(Person::getLast, Function.identity())
```

and instead of `Function.identity`, you can simply use the equivalent lambda:

```
Collectors.toMap(Person::getLast, p -> p)
```

If you use Netbeans you should get hints whenever an anonymous class can be replaced by a lambda.

Comment: You can make your expressions even shorter by removing parentheses as they are not needed for single arguments, i.e. `Collectors.toMap(Person::getLast, p -> p)`.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure the type argument for the identity function is not required as it can be inferred. `Collectors.toMap(Person::getLast, Function.identity())`

Comment: @GuiSim I think it is now the case indeed - it was a bug in the earlier versions of Java 8.

Comment: Hehe, it seems the p -> p is optimized somehow, no new compiled anonymous class is built. I guess it uses Function.identity() internally, instead of creating a useless class.

Comment: Important caveat! If your List contains null values, you will get an exception here because of how Collectors.toMap is implemented, even though a map with null values is normally perfectly acceptable. Surely in this case you would get an NPE anyway when accessing Person::getLast but there are many other cases where your key might be composed differently but you would still get the exception. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap

Answer (score 32):

```
List<Person> roster = ...;

Map<String, Person> map = 
    roster
        .stream()
        .collect(
            Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getLast(), p -> p)
        );
```

that would be the translation, but i havent run this or used the API. most likely you can substitute p -> p, for Function.identity(). and statically import toMap(...)

Comment: Is there a way of merging similar values in a List<Person> in case of duplicates instead of concatening them?

Answer (score 7):

We can use an optional merger function also in case of same key collision.
For example, If two or more persons have the same getLast() value, we can specify how to merge the values. If we not do this, we could get IllegalStateException.
Here is the example to achieve this...

```
Map<String, Person> map = 
roster
    .stream()
    .collect(
        Collectors.toMap(p -> p.getLast(),
                         p -> p,
                         (person1, person2) -> person1+";"+person2)
    );
```

Comment: I'm sorry but what does it mean ? `(person1, person2) -> person1+";"+person2)`

Comment: If the mapped keys contains duplicates (according to Object.equals(Object)), the value mapping function is applied to each equal element, and the results are merged using the provided merging function. Pls refer to the link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-