# Stream of maps to map

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How can I flatten a `Stream` of `Map`s (of the same types) to a single `Map` in Java 8?

```
Map<String, Long> toMap(Stream<Map<String, Long>> stream) {
    return stream. ???
}
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

My syntax may be a bit off, but flatMap should do most of the work for you :

```
Map<String, Long> toMap(Stream<Map<String, Long>> stream) {
    return stream.flatMap (map -> map.entrySet().stream()) // this would create a flattened
                                                           // Stream of all the map entries
                 .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(),
                                           e -> e.getValue())); // this should collect
                                                               // them to a single map
}
```

Comment: The method stream() is undefined for the type Map<String,Long>

Comment: @DariuszMydlarz I fixed the answer. Use map.entrySet().stream() instead.

Comment: You can use method references: `Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue)` (or if you import the nested class: `Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue)`)

Comment: Note that the 2-parameter `toMap(...)` will throw an exception if the same key occurs more than once.  If that's not what you want, use the 3-parameter `toMap(...)`.  Use `(a,b)->b` as the third parameter to emulate `Map::addAll` (later values overwrite previous ones).

Comment: This doesn't work if values are null. Also if maps have conflicting keys there will be merge exception.

Method given here is better
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap

Answer (score 1):

I would like to propose a solution using [reduce()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html#reduce), which is more intuitive for me. I would use it inline though.

```
Map<String, Long> toMap(Stream<Map<String, Long>> stream) {
    return stream.reduce(new HashMap<>(), Util::reduceInto);
}
```

And in Util.java:

```
public static <R, T> Map<R, T> reduceInto(Map<R, T> into, Map<R, T> valuesToAdd) {
    reduceInto.putAll(valuesToAdd);
    return reduceInto;
}
```

In this case reduceInto() works for any type of map and uses mutability to avoid creating a new Map for each item of the Stream.

**Important**: although this method allows repeated keys in the stream, reduceInto() **is not** [associative](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Associativity), meaning that if you have repeated keys there is no guarantee of which will be the final value.