# Java 8 Convert Map<String, String[]> to Map<String,String>

Tags: java, dictionary, lambda, java-8, java-stream

**UPDATE (after question marked as duplicate):** Duplicate question/answer does not help me solve my issue, as the map I am getting is from external source.

I am trying to work something out using Java `stream` and `collect` features.

I have a map of `Map<String, String[]>` which I needs to convert to a `Map<String, String>` picking up the first element of the `String` array if it's not empty or putting `null` if it's `null` or `empty`

```
private Map<String, String> convertMyMap(Map<String, String[]> originalMap) {

        return originalMap.entrySet().stream().collect(
             Collectors.toMap(
                 e -> e.getKey(), 
                 e -> {
                          if (ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(e.getValue()))
                               return e.getValue()[0];
                          return null;
                       }
             ));
```

I use below code to test it

```
Map<String, String[]> params =  new HashMap<String, String[]>();

params.put("test", new String[]{"1"});
params.put("test1", new String[]{"2", "1"});

//params.put("test2", new String[]{});   // THIS THROWS NPE
//params.put("test3", null);             // THIS THROWS NPE

convertMyMap(params).forEach((key, value) -> System.out.println(key + " "+ value));
```

As you can see when I try this with an empty array or null value for my original map, it throws NPE.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.HashMap.merge(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.Collectors.lambda$toMap$172(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$3ReducingSink.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReduceOps$ReduceOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.collect(Unknown Source)
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap

Comment: This explains the exception for `params.put("test3", null);`, but what about `params.put("test2", new String[]{});`?

Comment: @Turing85 If the array is empty, the mapped value is also null. The problem is not with how the original map is filled but how the one built with the collector is.

Comment: @AlexisC. huh funny, true that. Haven't thought of this. Thanks for the explanation

Comment: You could use `params.put("test2", new String[]{null});`

Comment: Duplicate question/answer does not help me solve my issue, as the map I am getting is from external source.

Comment: @AbubakkarRangara Look at the second answer.

Comment: @Abubakkar Rangara: you should read and try to understand the answers of the linked question. The Map is completely irrelevant. The second function passed to `toMap` is not allowed to return `null`.

Comment: Faster, simpler, working code is achieved without using streams. `private static Map<String,String> convertMyMap(Map<String,String[]> originalMap) { Map<String,String> newMap = new HashMap<>(); for (Map.Entry<String,String[]> e : originalMap.entrySet()) newMap.put(e.getKey(), ArrayUtils.isNotEmpty(e.getValue()) ? e.getValue()[0] : null); return newMap; }`

Comment: @Boann I already have that implementation, but wanted to try this with streams, collectors in Java 8