# java stream throws NPE when toMap stores a null value

Tags: java-8

`HashMap` allows to store `NULL` value, but `Stream.toMap(r-> r.getName(), r->r.get(obj))` would throw NPE when `r.get(obj)` returns null? Do I miss something or `Stream` has a special reason to be more careful than `Map`? I am trying to use reflection and java8 to achieve `(new ObjectMapper()).convertValue(obj, Obj.class);`

Comment: Have a look here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap

Comment: @LachezarBalev thanks, so they don't have a special reason. but i still don't think it is a good idea to have a different behavior of a well-known structure as they look the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Collector.toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-) uses [HashMap::merge](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) to combine results:

```
public V merge(K key, V value,
               BiFunction<? super V, ? super V, ? extends V> remappingFunction) {
    if (value == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
    if (remappingFunction == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();
```

So it may store null values, but merge does not allow it.

You can do a work around, by using forEach

```
stream.forEach (
   r-> map.put(r.getName(), r.get(obj))
)
```

Comment: I wouldn't use this workaround, but instead a standard collect: `stream().collect(HashMap::new, (m, r) -> m.put(r.getName(), r.get(obj)), Map::putAll);`

Comment: @AlexisC. Very good idea. Should be the way to do it if HashMap is expected.

Comment: @AlexisC. signature for `putall` is `void putAll(Map<? extends K, ? extends V> m);` while for `collect` is `<R> R collect(Supplier<R> supplier,
                  BiConsumer<R, ? super T> accumulator,
                  BiConsumer<R, R> combiner);`  `combiner` takes two argument, why `putall` taking one `map` fits `combiner` taking `T` and `U`?

Comment: @Tiina Try checking this link: http://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/core-java-tutorial/java-util-stream/collect/ . The combiner is used only in parallel streams, and it must be an  associative function.