# How to filter the Map with Stream when null occurs?

Tags: java, dictionary, nullpointerexception, java-8, java-stream

I want to filter some values in the `Map` via `Stream`. Let's see the simple example, where I want to extract entries with keys, for example, higher than 2.

Here is the code I use:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<>(); 
map.put(1, "one"); 
map.put(2, "two"); 
map.put(3, "three"); 
map.put(4, "four"); 

Map<Integer, String> map2 = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey() > 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));

System.out.println(map2.toString());
```

The result correct:

> {3=three, 4=four}

When I decide to put the String value as `null`, that's legal, this is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Here is the continuation of the code:

```
map.put(5, null);
map.put(6, "six");

Map<Integer, String> map3 = map.entrySet().stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getKey() > 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));

System.out.println(map3.toString());
```

I would expect the result:

> {3=three, 4=four, 5=null, 6=six}

Well, it works when I change the condition in the filter's `Predicate` to `e -> e.getKey() < 2` since the `null` value is unaffected. How to handle this with `Stream`? The `null` value may occur anywhere intentionally. I don't want to use the for-loop. Shouldn't `Stream` architecture be more "null-safe"?

The question [How should we manage jdk8 stream for null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17081063/how-should-we-manage-jdk8-stream-for-null-values) deals with the different problem. I don't want to use `.filter(Objects::nonNull)` because I need to keep the `null` values.

---

Please don't mark it as duplicate with famous [What is a NullPointerException and how do I fix it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it). I know this well, I ask the solution using `Stream`, that is not as low-level as for-loop is. This behaviour quite limits me.

Comment: Tired of Null Pointer Exceptions? Consider Using Java SE 8's Optional!

Comment: Would you give me an example applied to my sample problem? I am not familiar with the `Optional`.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43606886/java-stream-throws-npe-when-tomap-stores-a-null-value)

Comment: I'm sorry, it doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis with current `toMap` implementation you can't put null values. You have to create own `collector` - this is described in one of answers in linked question

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidis How is that the linked questions (along with their answers) don't answer your question?

Comment: Unless you are not telling us something, then it is a duplicate. the exact answer is this: `Map<Integer, String> map3 = map.entrySet().stream().filter(e -> e.getKey() > 2).collect(HashMap::new, (map, entry) -> map.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()), HashMap::putAll);` Would this satisfy your needs?

Comment: @Eugene, yea, this is what I need. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: because that *is* the answer in one of the linked questions... But it should not matter - it's good that you find your solution

Comment: I have used the similar in the wrong way, my bad... Also I am happy you give me lot of time to edit my question (since I am not online 24/7). You can close it if you wish a lot.

Comment: actually you can close it too... or even delete it. I would delete it to be honest :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Optional is a container object which is used to contain not-null objects. Optional object is used to represent null with absent value.

You can do something like this:

```
Map<Integer, Optional<String>> map = new HashMap<>(); 

//Optional.ofNullable - allows passed parameter to be null.
map.put(1, Optional.ofNullable("one")); 
map.put(2, Optional.ofNullable("two")); 
map.put(3, Optional.ofNullable(null)); 
map.put(4, Optional.ofNullable("four")); 

Map<Integer, Optional<String>> map2 = map.entrySet().stream()
        .filter(e -> e.getKey() > 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.getKey(), e -> e.getValue()));

System.out.println(map2.toString());
```

**Test**

```
{3=Optional.empty, 4=Optional[four]}
```

For more utility methods to facilitate code to handle values as *available* or *not available* instead of checking `null` values, I refer you to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: Yes, it may solve my problem. However, my goal is to get the new `Map` back with the new values including `null`. It means I have to check the value with `.isPresent()`?

Comment: @NikolasCharalambidist The idea of `Optional` is to achieve what you want. You need to replace the second type argument `String` with `Optional<String>` then work with it.

Comment: Yahya, I initially downvoted your answer, but I immediately reverted it, without reading your previous comment. I downvoted because you were not answering what the OP was asking, but then I thought that I was being too harsh, because even though OP was not asking about `Optional`, you were providing a workaround. However, a better way to solve this problem is to use a custom collector. Anyways, this is a duplicate question, check the answers of the linked original questions to find out. And sorry for being too quick and harsh with my downvote.