# Collecting values that could be null

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, java-stream, key-value

I have the following code:

```
private static <T> Map<String, ?> getDifference(final T a, final T b, final Map<String, Function<T, Object>> fields) {
    return fields.entrySet().stream()
            .map(e -> {
                final String name = e.getKey();
                final Function<T, Object> getter = e.getValue();
                final Object pairKey = getter.apply(a);
                final Object pairValue = getter.apply(b);
                if (Objects.equals(pairKey, pairValue)) {
                    return null;
                } else {
                    return Pair.of(name, pairValue);
                }
            })
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue));
}
```

Now, pairValue can be null. In order to avoid the NPE as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap), while "collect"-ing, I wish to ensure that I send only those values that are non-null. If null, I want to send "".

So, I tried replacing the last line with this:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey,Optional.ofNullable(Pair::getValue).orElse(""));
```

And other modifications thereof:

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(pair -> pair.getKey(), Optional.ofNullable(pair -> pair.getValue()).orElse(""));
```

Does not compile. I'm not sure what is needed here. Any help?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what doesn't work? Does the computer catch fire?

Comment: Java 8 NullPointerException in Collectors.toMap https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap Is this the same problem?

Comment: It doesn't compile, edited the question.

Comment: I'm trying to do a null check to avoid the NPE. The code above doesn't compile.

Comment: What does the duplicate have to do with this question? i.e. this question has no mention of an array...

Comment: Yeah, I have no idea! How do I get rid of the duplicate tag?

Comment: Unfortunately there's not much that I can do at the moment.  I voted to reopen the question and flagged it for moderator intervention, so we'll see what happens.

Comment: @user2116243 It seems it was removed!

Comment: [mcve] with test data could be helpful.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NullPointerException in Collectors.toMap with null entry values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap-with-null-entry-values)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have incorrect syntax. `toMap()`'s second parameter must be lambda, so

```
.collect(Collectors.toMap(
             pair -> pair.getKey(),
             pair -> Optional.ofNullable(pair.getValue()).orElse("")
));
```

**OR**

you can modify `map()` section as follows

```
return Pair.of(name, Optional.ofNullable(pairValue).orElse(""));
```

and use your original `collect()`

Answer (score 10):

You can just collect into a `HashMap` which allows `null` values without the need for an `Optional`:

```
private static <T> Map<String, Object> getDifference(
        final T a, final T b, final Map<String, Function<T, Object>> fields) {
    return fields.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> {
            final Function<T, Object> getter = e.getValue();
            final Object value = getter.apply(b);
            return Objects.equals(getter.apply(a),value)? null: Pair.of(e.getKey(), value);
        })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(HashMap::new, (m,p) -> m.put(p.getKey(),p.getValue()), Map::putAll);
}
```

By the way, it is discouraged to use wildcards in return types, they can make the caller’s life unnecessarily hard for no benefit.

For comparison, here the same operation without Stream:

```
private static <T> Map<String, Object> getDifference(
        final T a, final T b, final Map<String, Function<T, Object>> fields) {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    fields.forEach((key, getter) -> {
        final Object value = getter.apply(b);
        if(!Objects.equals(getter.apply(a), value)) result.put(key, value);
    });
    return result;
}
```

Of course, this would also work with optional:

```
private static <T> Map<String, Optional<Object>> getDifference(
        final T a, final T b, final Map<String, Function<T, Object>> fields) {
    HashMap<String, Optional<Object>> result = new HashMap<>();
    fields.forEach((key, getter) -> {
        final Object value = getter.apply(b);
        if(!Objects.equals(getter.apply(a), value))
            result.put(key, Optional.ofNullable(value));
    });
    return result;
}
```

---

But if all you want to do, is replace `null` with an empty string, you don’t need an `Optional`:

```
private static <T> Map<String, Object> getDifference(
        final T a, final T b, final Map<String, Function<T, Object>> fields) {
    HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
    fields.forEach((key,getter) -> {
            final Object value = getter.apply(b);
            if(!Objects.equals(getter.apply(a), value))
                result.put(key, value==null? "": value);
        });
    return result;
}
```

and well, this substitution would also work out-of-the-box with your original code, if you just do it in the `map` function instead of the collector:

```
private static <T> Map<String, ?> getDifference(final T a, final T b, final Map<String, Function<T, Object>> fields) {
    return fields.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> {
            final String name = e.getKey();
            final Function<T, Object> getter = e.getValue();
            final Object pairKey = getter.apply(a);
            final Object pairValue = getter.apply(b);
            if (Objects.equals(pairKey, pairValue)) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return Pair.of(name, pairValue==null? "": pairValue);
            }
        })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue));
}
```

or

```
private static <T> Map<String, Object> getDifference(
        final T a, final T b, final Map<String, Function<T, Object>> fields) {
    return fields.entrySet().stream()
        .map(e -> {
            final Function<T, Object> getter = e.getValue();
            final Object pairValue = getter.apply(b);
            return Objects.equals(getter.apply(a), pairValue)? null:
                Pair.of(e.getKey(), pairValue==null? "": pairValue);
        })
        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Pair::getKey, Pair::getValue));
}
```