# Create a map from two different lists based on common conditions using Java 8 Streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have two list instances like this:

```
List<NameAndAge> nameAndAgeList = new ArrayList<>();
nameAndAgeList.add(new NameAndAge("John", "28"));
nameAndAgeList.add(new NameAndAge("Paul", "30"));
nameAndAgeList.add(new NameAndAge("Adam", "31"));

List<NameAndSalary> nameAndSalaryList = new ArrayList<>();
nameAndSalaryList.add(new NameAndSalary("John", 1000));
nameAndSalaryList.add(new NameAndSalary("Paul", 1100));
nameAndSalaryList.add(new NameAndSalary("Adam", 1200));
```

where `NameAndAge` is

```
class NameAndAge {
    public String name;
    public String age;

    public NameAndAge(String name, String age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + age;
    }
}
```

and `NameAndSalary` is

```
private class NameAndSalary {
    private String name;
    private double salary;

    public NameAndSalary(String name, double salary) {
        this.name = name;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + salary;
    }
}
```

Now, I want to create a map with key as `NameAndAge` object from the first list and value as `NameAndSalary` from the second list where the name is equal in both the objects.

So, when I print the map, it should look like this:

```
{John: 28=John: 1000.0}
{Paul: 30=Paul: 1100.0}
{Adam: 31=Adam: 1200.0}
```

I have tried doing this, but the end return type is 'void' so I'm stuck clueless as I am new to Streams.

```
nameAndAgeList
    .forEach(n ->
        nameAndSalaryList
            .stream()
            .filter(ns -> ns.name.equals(n.name))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

Can someone please advise how can this be achieved with Java Streams API?

Comment: Shouldn't the _equal_ sign in the representation be a _comma_, actually?

Comment: @Matt, since it's a sysout of a map, it would rather print equal instead of a comma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick, too:

```
Map<NameAndAge, NameAndSalary> map = new HashMap<>();
nameAndAgeList.forEach(age -> {
     NameAndSalary salary = nameAndSalaryList.stream().filter(
              s -> age.getName().equals(s.getName())).
              findFirst().
              orElseThrow(IllegalStateException::new);
      map.put(age, salary);
});
```

Mind that it would throw an `IllegalStateException` if a matching name can't be found.

Comment: This precisely does what I want. Thanks @Matt

Answer (score 10):

First of all, assuming you are going to create a `HashMap`, your key class (`NameAndAge`) must override `equals` and `hashCode()`.

Second of all, in order to be efficient, I suggest you first create a `Map<String,NameAndSalary>` from the second `List`:

```
Map<String,NameAndSalary> helper =
    nameAndSalaryList.stream()
                     .collect(Collectors.toMap(NameAndSalary::getName,
                                               Function.identity()));
```

Finally, you can create the `Map` you want:

```
Map<NameAndAge,NameAndSalary> output = 
    nameAndAgeList.stream()
                  .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(),
                                            naa->helper.get(naa.getName())));
```

Comment: I was in the middle of writing a similar answer.  There are other assumptions that must be made without adding additional complexity:  (1) that the names are unique, and (2) a given name should always appear in objects in both lists.

Comment: @WilliamPrice yes, if the names are not unique , you must add a merge function to `Collectors.toMap()`. As for the second assumption, you can ignore it. If a name appears only on the first list, the corresponding NameAndAge will be assigned a null value in the output Map. If a name appears only on the second list, it won't appear on the output Map.

Comment: [Collectors.toMap() will throw NPE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap) if either the key _or the value_ is `null`, even if the destination map implementation would allow it.

Comment: Thanks @Eran. Although it worked for me, I am still trying to understand what Function.identity() is and all other such stuff as I am pretty new to streams (which is irrelevant to the question I posted). Also agree with your point of adding hashcode and equals, but since in my case, they are always unique entries, there may not be an impact of not overriding them

Comment: @WilliamPrice, Yes. In my case, the names are always unique and there is always going to be a matching name in both the lists. Thanks for pointing it out though

Comment: @Ravi `Function.identity()` is a function that returns whatever you pass into it. When you use `Function.identity()` as the key generator of the `toMap` collector, this means that the keys will be the elements of the `Stream` (i.e. the `NameAndAge` instances in the second Stream pipeline).

Comment: Aah I see. Thanks @Eran. I now understand what it is. This is similar to naa -> naa right?

Comment: This is the only solution that is even *close* to being 1. maintainable (maybe even more when pulling these lines out into generic methods like `mapWithKeys` and `mapWithValues`) and 2. efficient in that it is O(n), and does not search the whole second list for each element that is found in the first one (which is O(n^2)).

Answer (score 0):

This should work too

```
List<String> commonNames = nameAndAgeList
    .stream()
    .filter(na -> 
         nameAndSalaryList.anyMatch((ns) -> ns.getName().equals(na.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());

Map<NameAndAge, NameAndSalary> map = 
    commonNames.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(name -> 
        nameAndAgeList.get(name), name -> nameAndSalaryList.get(name)));
```

Answer (score -2):

Without creating any intermediate object, without using a `forEach`, one liner:

```
Map<NameAndAge, NameAndSalary> resultMap1 = nameAndAgeList.stream()
            .map(nameAndAge -> nameAndSalaryList.stream()
                    .filter(nameAndSalary -> nameAndAge.getName().equals(nameAndSalary.getName()))
                    .map(nameAndSalary -> new SimpleEntry<>(nameAndAge, nameAndSalary))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()).get(0))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(simpleEntry -> simpleEntry.getKey(), simpleEntry -> simpleEntry.getValue()));
```

You will have to add the `getter` functions to the domain classes though. Accessing the properties directly might not be a good idea.