# Order a Map that contains String, but strings might represent a number

Tags: java

I have this kind of values inside a Map:

```
Map<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();                  
map.put(1,"mark");
map.put(2,"1.1");
map.put(3,"google");
map.put(4,"12");
map.put(5,"2.2);
```

I need to order this Map, ordering both numbers and strings.

What I get now is this (as you can see numbers are not "ordered" since are String)

```
1.1
12
2.2
google
mark
```

What I should  get is:

```
1.1
2.2
12
google
mark
```

How can I do it? I'm a little confused.

Comment: What do you mean by ordering a map? (A `HashMap` is not ordered). Can you show your code?

Comment: make a simple mapper returning Float.parse if numeric string, `Float.MAX_VALUE` otherwise, and use a comparator based on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need a map you can use a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) which is sorted by insertion order. To compare the values you can create your own comparator:

```
Comparator<String> stringAndNumberComparator = (s1, s2) -> {
    try {
        return Double.valueOf(s1).compareTo(Double.valueOf(s2));
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return s1.compareTo(s2);
    }
};
```

Now you can use a java stream to sort the entry set of your map and collect it back to a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
Map<Integer, String> sorted = map.entrySet().stream()
        .sorted(Map.Entry.comparingByValue(stringAndNumberComparator))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (s1, s2) -> s1, LinkedHashMap::new));
```

Alternatively you can use the comparator provided in the [answer from *Karol Dowbecki*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56345392/9662601) with `Map.Entry.comparingByValue()`.

The result will be `{2=1.1, 5=2.2, 4=12, 3=google, 1=mark}`;

If you just need a list of your values you can just use this:

```
List<String> sorted = map.values().stream()
        .sorted(stringAndNumberComparator)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result in this case will be `[1.1, 2.2, 12, google, mark]`.

Comment: Thank you maaaaaaaaaan. I tried it and it works. :) When I can't use .compareTo() , because s1 or s2 is null, what value should I return in order not to "ruin" the sorted map?

Comment: @MDP You can add null checks before. e.g. `if (s1 == null) return -1; if (s2 == null) return 1;` but you will get an `Exception` using `Collectors.toMap()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/24630963/9662601 for more info on that. Another option would be to filter non null values before or replace them by default non null values.

Answer (score 5):

You can't order a `Map` by entry value. `SortedMap` e.g. `TreeMap` allows to order the entries by key. It seems you might be using a wrong data structure.

In your example you can define a function that will leniently parse a `double` and return `Double.NaN` instead of an exception:

```
private double lenientParseDouble(String s) {
    try {
        return Double.parseDouble(s);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        return Double.NaN;
    }
}
```

As per `Double.compare()` docs:

> `Double.NaN` is considered by this method to be equal to itself and greater than all other double values (including `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY`).

and then use it as part of the `Comparator` chain

```
map.values().stream()
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(this::lenientParseDouble).thenComparing(Function.identity()))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thank you man, it works.
I've never seen this synthax.
I have to get the sorted value (to add them to a List) instead of printing them with System.out? Thank you