# Inserting Map into Map using streams

Tags: java

I'd like to know how I can insert a map into another map using streams in java.

I have a two maps

```
    Map<String, List<Character>> map1

    Map<String, List<Integer>> map2
```

I d like to merge both maps such that we have

```
    Map<String, Map<Character, Integer>> finalmap
```

if map1 is something like

```
    {String1 = [Character1, Character2], String2 = [Character3, Character4], etc}
```

and map2 is

```
    {String1 = [Integer1, Integer2], String2 = [Integer3, Integer4], etc}
```

I want it to merge such that the innermap maps Character1 with Integer1 and so on.
Does someone have an idea how to solve this problem? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Map<String, Map<Character, Integer>> map3 = map1.entrySet()
                .stream()
                .flatMap(entry -> {
                    if (map2.containsKey(entry.getKey())) {
                        List<Integer> integers = map2.get(entry.getKey());
                        List<Character> characters = entry.getValue();
                        Map<Character, Integer> innerMap = IntStream.range(0, Math.min(integers.size(), characters.size()))
                                .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(characters.get(i), integers.get(i)))
                                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

                        return Stream.of(Map.entry(entry.getKey(), innerMap));
                    }

                    return Stream.empty();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit late but in case the length of `Character` and `Integer` lists is different, it may be possible to build an inner map containing all `Character` keys and `null` for missing `Integer` values:

```java
// class MyClass
static Map<String, Map<Character, Integer>> joinMaps(
    Map<String, List<Character>> map1, Map<String, List<Integer>> map2) 
{
    return map1
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .filter(e -> map2.containsKey(e.getKey())) // keep the keys from both maps
            .map(e -> Map.entry(
                e.getKey(), // String key for result
                IntStream.range(0, e.getValue().size()) // build map <Character, Integer>
                         .mapToObj(i -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                             e.getValue().get(i), 
                             i < map2.get(e.getKey()).size() ? map2.get(e.getKey()).get(i) : null
                         ))
                         // use custom collector to allow null Integer values
                         .collect(
                             MyClass::innerMap, 
                             (hm, e2) -> hm.put(e2.getKey(), e2.getValue()),
                             Map::putAll
                         )
            ))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
}
    
static LinkedHashMap<Character, Integer> innerMap() {
    return new LinkedHashMap<>();
}
```

Custom collector for inner map is needed to allow adding `null` values which is not possible with `Collectors.toMap` where [NPE is thrown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap).

Tests:

```java
Map<String, List<Character>> map1 = Map.of(
    "S0", Arrays.asList('#', '@'),
    "S1", Arrays.asList('a', 'b'),
    "S2", Arrays.asList('c', 'd'),
    "S3", Arrays.asList('e', 'f')
);
System.out.println("map1=" + map1);

Map<String, List<Integer>> map2 = Map.of(
    "S1", Arrays.asList(1),
    "S2", Arrays.asList(3, 4, 5),
    "S3", Arrays.asList(5, 6),
    "S4", Arrays.asList(7, 8)
);
System.out.println("map2=" + map2);

Map<String, Map<Character, Integer>> res = joinMaps(map1, map2);       
System.out.println("----\nResult:");
res.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", k, v));
```

Output:

```
map1={S0=[#, @], S1=[a, b], S2=[c, d], S3=[e, f]}
map2={S1=[1], S2=[3, 4, 5], S3=[5, 6], S4=[7, 8]}
----
Result:
S1 -> {a=1, b=null}
S2 -> {c=3, d=4}
S3 -> {e=5, f=6}
```

---

**Update**
Another solution using `Stream::flatMap` and `groupingBy + mapping` collectors with a custom collector used as a downstream collector is shown below:

```java
static Map<String, Map<Character, Integer>> joinMaps(
    Map<String, List<Character>> map1, Map<String, List<Integer>> map2) 
{
    return map1
        .entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(e -> map2.containsKey(e.getKey()))
        .flatMap(e -> IntStream.range(0, e.getValue().size())
            .mapToObj(i -> Map.entry(
                e.getKey(),
                new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(
                    e.getValue().get(i), 
                    i < map2.get(e.getKey()).size() ? map2.get(e.getKey()).get(i) : null
                )
        ))) // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Map.Entry<Character, Integer>>>
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
            Map.Entry::getKey,  // use String as key in outer map
            Collectors.mapping(e -> e.getValue(), // build inner map
                Collector.of(                     // using custom collector
                    MyClass::innerMap, // supplier
                    (hm, e2) -> hm.put(e2.getKey(), e2.getValue()), // accumulator
                    MyClass::mergeMaps // combiner
            ))
        ));
}

static <T extends Map> T mergeMaps(T acc, T map) {
    acc.putAll(map);
    return acc;
}
```

Here `mergeMaps` is a `BinaryOperator<A> combiner` argument in the method [`Collector.of`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html#of-java.util.function.Supplier-java.util.function.BiConsumer-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-java.util.stream.Collector.Characteristics...-) which slightly differs from [`Stream::collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) used above where `BiConsumer<R, R>` is used as combiner.