# Instantiate a Map from a set of key objects, in Java

Tags: java, dictionary, set, instantiation

Given a `Set` of objects that I want to use as keys, how can I easily get a `Map` instance leaving the values as null?

The purpose is to pre-populate the map with keys before determining the values to be stored.

Of course, I could create an empty map, then loop the set of would-be key objects, while doing a `put` on each, along with `null` as the value.

```java
Set< Month > months = EnumSet.of( Month.MARCH , Month.MAY , Month.JUNE ) ; 
Map< Month , String > map = new EnumMap<>( Month.class ) ;
for( Month month : months ) 
{
    map.put( month , null ) ;
}
```

I just wonder if there is a nifty trick to do this with less code. Something like the opposite of [`Map#keySet`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Map.html#keySet()).

Comment: What kind of `Map`? You could write your own `Map` implementation that accepts a `Set` for initialization and/or is backed by a `Set`. Else it's not possible. Either use a for-loop or `Stream` (which is essentially the same as a for-loop). `...` **EDIT:** What's the reason for pre-populating the `Map` with keys?

Comment: @BenjaminM Any `Map` implementation would do. I could always pass that map to the constructor of another `Map` I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Collectors.toMap()` and the static factory methods like `Map.of()` use internally  `Map.merge` which will throw NPE if key or value is null.

See this post: [java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/java-8-nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap). And see this issue page on the OpenJDK project: [*JDK-8148463 Collectors.toMap fails on null values*](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8148463)

You could work around by using [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect(java.util.function.Supplier,java.util.function.BiConsumer,java.util.function.BiConsumer)) with the three args signature as a reduction.

```
collect(Supplier supplier, BiConsumer accumulator, BiConsumer combiner)
```

Something like:

```java
Set< Month > months = EnumSet.of( Month.MARCH , Month.MAY , Month.JUNE ) ;         
Map< Month , String > myMap = 
        months.stream()
              .collect(
                  HashMap::new , 
                  ( map , val )-> map.put( val , null ) , 
                  HashMap::putAll
              );
              
System.out.println(myMap);
```

See that [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/TOfjro).

But I'm not sure if this is either more readable or more elegant than your approach with the classic for-loop

Answer (score 1):

```
set.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(k -> k, k -> null));
```

Comment: I cannot seem to get that code to work. I’m not sure about the runtime error. I suspect that null values are not tolerated. See code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/xvWmgB).

Comment: That code does work if we use empty string as the value rather than null. See [this code on IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/8cotE3).  `Map< Month , String > map = Set.of( Month.MARCH , Month.MAY , Month.JUNE ).stream().collect( Collectors.toMap( k -> k , k -> "" ) );`