# Java Stream fill map from two lists by the first list items as keys

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, java-stream

I have two lists that I need to check that every product (from `products`) has a code (from `productCodes`)

```
List<String> productCodes = List.of("X_14_AA_85", "X_14_BB_85", "X_14_ZZ_85");
List<String> products = List.of("AA", "BB", "CC", "ZZ");

// I want to achieve a collection of (product code, product)
// according if product name exists in productCode name

// key - product code, value - product
/*
Map<String, String> map = Map.of(
  "AA", "X_14_AA_85",
  "BB", "X_14_BB_85",
  "CC", null,          // null if code doesn't exist
  "ZZ", "X_14_ZZ_85" 
);
*/
// after a filter with null keys I could return a message something like this
// List<String> nullableProducts = List.of("CC");
// return "I could prompt that there's no code for product/s: " + nullableProducts;
```

Is there a way with streams to filter by list item values?

Comment: Map keys cannot be `null`!

Comment: @TimothyTruckle I've switched places now, but the concept remains

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/java-collectors-tomap  I down voted because 
[No research](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)
[No attempt](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, `HashMap` allows `null` for both keys and values

Comment: @AlexRudenko https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#of-K-V-K-V- "Throws:
    IllegalArgumentException - if the keys are duplicates
    NullPointerException - if any key or value is null"

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, this refers to the immutable map, returned by `Map.of`

Comment: In your declaration are product and product codes mixed up? For example, Product BB can't contain any of the codes.  It's too short.

Answer (score 0):

You can `stream` the `keySet` and filter `null` values:

**Java 16+**:

```
List<String> list = map.keySet().stream()
        .filter(key -> map.get(key) == null).toList();
```

**Java 15 and older:**

```
List<String> list = map.keySet().stream()
        .filter(key -> map.get(key) == null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**Note:** You can't instantiate an unmodifiable `Map` using `Map.of()` with `null` keys or values. Instead, you can do:

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("AA", "X_14_AA_85");
map.put("BB", "X_14_BB_85");
map.put("CC", null);
map.put("ZZ", "X_14_ZZ_85");
```

Answer (score 0):

If the purpose is to get a map containing `null` value, this has to be implemented using a [custom collector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24630963/nullpointerexception-in-collectors-tomap-with-null-entry-values), because existing implementation throws `NullPointerException` when putting `null`:

```java
List<String> productCodes = List.of("X_14_AA_85", "X_14_BB_85", "X_14_ZZ_85");
List<String> products = List.of("AA", "BB", "CC", "ZZ");

Map<String, String> mapCodes = products.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(
        HashMap::new, 
        (m, p) -> m.put(p, productCodes
            .stream()
            .filter(pc -> pc.contains(p))
            .findFirst()
            .orElse(null)
        ), 
        HashMap::putAll
    );
// -> {AA=X_14_AA_85, BB=X_14_BB_85, CC=null, ZZ=X_14_ZZ_85}
```

Then the list of non-matched products may be retrieved as follows:

```java
List<String> nonMatchedProducts = mapCodes.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue() == null)
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
// -> [CC]
```

---

However, as the result of `findFirst` is returned as `Optional` it may be used along with `Collectors::toMap`, and then the non-matched values can be filtered out using `Optional::isEmpty`:

```java
Map<String, Optional<String>> mapCodes2 = products.stream()
    .distinct()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        p -> p,
        p -> productCodes.stream().filter(pc -> pc.contains(p)).findFirst()
    ));
// -> {AA=Optional[X_14_AA_85], BB=Optional[X_14_BB_85], CC=Optional.empty, ZZ=Optional[X_14_ZZ_85]}

List<String> nonMatchedProducts2 = mapCodes2.entrySet()
    .stream()
    .filter(e -> e.getValue().isEmpty())
    .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
// -> [CC]
```

---

Also, the null/empty values may not be stored at all, then non-matched products can be found after removing all the matched ones:

```java
Map<String, String> map3 = new HashMap<>();
for (String p : products) {
    productCodes.stream()
        .filter(pc -> pc.contains(p))
        .findFirst()
        .ifPresent(pc -> map3.put(p, pc)); // only matched pairs
}
// -> {AA=X_14_AA_85, BB=X_14_BB_85, ZZ=X_14_ZZ_85}
List<String> nonMatchedProducts3 = new ArrayList<>(products);
nonMatchedProducts3.removeAll(map3.keySet());
// -> [CC]
```

Answer (score 0):

Given your two lists, I would do something like this. I added two products that contain non-existent codes.

```
List<String> products =
        List.of("X_14_AA_85", "X_14_SS_88", "X_14_BB_85", "X_14_ZZ_85", "X_16_RR_85");
List<String> productCodes = List.of("AA", "BB", "CC", "ZZ");
```

Declare a lambda to extract the code and copy the codes to a set for efficient lookup. In fact, since duplicates codes aren't necessary, a `set` would be the preferred data structure from the start.

Assuming the product code is the same place and length, you can do it like this using substring.  Otherwise you may need to use a regular expression to parse the product string.

```
Function<String, String> extractCode =
        code -> code.substring(5,7);
Set<String> productCodeSet = new HashSet<>(productCodes);
```

And run it like this.

```
List<String> missingCodes = products.stream()
        .filter(product -> !productCodeSet
                .contains(extractCode.apply(product)))
        .toList();

System.out.println("There are no codes for the following products: " + missingCodes);
```

Prints

```
There are no codes for the following products: [X_14_SS_88, X_16_RR_85]
```